# How can I select an object in the viewport in 2.8(1)?

Tags: objects, interface, edit-mode

I have imported a large model with lots (hundreds?) of objects. The hierarchy of the model is not very logical so I am trying to fix this.

Therefore I would like to select objects in the viewport to group them. But when I click (trying both the Tweak and Select box tools), nothing gets selected. When I select an object in the Outliner, it selects (and outlines) perfectly fine.
Selecting everything through the outliner is not an option as the object names are the same: group_nnnn (nnnn being a number)

I have tried switching from 'Layout' to 'Modelling' as I read somewhere here, but switching leaves me with an empty viewport.

What am I missing here?

[image]

Edit: added a screenshot

Non-empty empties??

[image]

With selectables on and empties unchecked:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the whole user interface? Perhaps you've disabled the overlay or something similar.

Comment: sure, i have added it

Comment: You're currently in edit mode. Switch to object mode and you should be able to select them properly.

Comment: You are right there @RobertGützkow, unforunately switching to object mode does not make selecting objects possible either.
A and Alt-A do work properly as does 'Select Pattern'.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm ... that's a lot of empties in the outliner ... let's hide them, **uncheck empties**

Also make sure that objects are selectable, **enable Selectable** in the *restriction toggles* - the one that looks like a paper airplane.

[image: Outliner options]

If you have checked that the objects are selectable then you need to check the *View Object Types Menu* has **Mesh selection enabled**:

[image: View Object Types Menu]

Comment: Thanks Moog, but empties is unchecked and even with Selectable selected I am still not able to select in the viewport. 

Strange thing: when I do check empties, the empties open up and have empties inside? (added a screenshot in the first post)

Comment: Thanks for thinking along @Moog! In '_Object Types Visibility_' it's all eyes and arrows. I have added a screenshot of the outliner.

Comment: I am willing to send this file it that would help, please dm me if that would be an option.

Comment: Tried uploading there but I can't see any results...

Comment: It's just under 150Mb, no code showed up and no error message either. I have even tried a different browser to upload..Seems software-mysteries are haunting me... I could WeTransfer it or zip -and-mail (yes, getting desperate here ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101817/discussion-between-moog-and-roguesheep).