# Appended objects in a collection have different dimensions compared to the original (2.81)

Tags: append

Appending a collection from a different file works fine but unfortunately the dimensions of the result are different.

Original:

[image]

Appended version:

[image]

Comment: Something else is going on, I'm appending collections on 2.81 without any scaling problem. Share your .blend file please

Comment: Thanks Arthur, I am not able to upload the file (was trying it for this post: [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159888/how-can-i-select-an-object-in-the-viewport-in-2-81)  Maybe it has become corrupted?) In an attempt to reorganize the imported fbx, I have been creating new collections based on selections. I'll retry once I have sorted things out with the file. Good to know this is caused by something quirky and is not default behavior.

Comment: For those stumbling upon this: the probable cause was a broken parent-relation. The append objects were probably scaled by their parent which was not appended. 
A solution might be (not tested): de-parent the objects (alt-p) + keep transform and then turn them into a collection to append.