# I cant select more than one object, or interact with it

Tags: modeling, interface, selection-tools, file-format, asset-browser

So I've been using blender for a few months now, and I haven't ever had something like this... I cant select any object, through the viewport or heirarchy, nor can i interact with it or anything. I have tried various fixes.

I wanted to get kitbash sets for myself and when i opened the file, I first couldn't see the outlines, tried to fix it, but the outline selected option, gizmos and origins were all on already, next, i tried selecting multiple objects with box select and it didnt do anything, then i selected one object and it worked, tho still no outline, and the main thing is that i couldn't interact with these objects in any way except selecting one, or through the heirarchy(which also doesn't highlight the selected object, and i cant shift select or ctrl select either).[image] I have tried everything i could think of and none of them have worked so far, im thinking that i should just download another format of it. I have tried opening other files by the same creator, but the same problem persists. The only reason i can think of is some sort of version incompatability with old blender versions to 3.0+

Edit: The same thing happens for recent files too though, i cant selec, interact or do anything, even when downloading an FBX format, after i open it again, i cant edit it at all.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/159907/86891 ?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the selectable toggle and check if the objects are marked unselectable in the heirarchy. It's the cursor icon, when disabled objects can't be interacted with in the viewport.

[image: Selectable toggle]
[image: Selectable toggled off]